# Google App Engine (python): filter users based on custom fields

Tags: google-app-engine, filter

i am using the `webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User` service which basically extends the `google.appengine.api.users model`. Now , I have custom users registered with my application and they have a lot of custom fields. The problem is i want to filter / (multi filter) all the users using various custom fields. For example:

the user model has 2 fields `is_active` and `activation_key` now i want to filter them using these fields, example:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

act_key = 'hw-2j38he63u83hd6hak3FshSqj3TGemn9'
user = users.all().filter('is_active =', False).filter('activation_key =', act_key).get()
if user:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

what are the best possible ways to filter on the user model using custom fields?

Edit:

Also tried the following:

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User

query = User.query().filter('is_active =', False)
print query
```

but this raises an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/google_appengine_1.6.4/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py", line 320, in post
exec(compiled_code, globals())
File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
File "lib/ndb/query.py", line 968, in filter
raise TypeError('Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received %r' % arg)
TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received 'is_active ='
```

Comment: Shouldn't you already know from context what user you're fetching an activation key for? In which case, it would make more sense to fetch the record by ID, then check the key matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User` is an Expando model with `created`, `updated`, `auth_ids` and `password` properties. Everything beyond that or *custom properties* would be stored as an opaque blob, i.e., wouldn't be indexed. That said, one can't query/filter on them.

You could subclass the `User` model and add properties you need or (which is better) create a new model (say `Account`).

This is a good habit when dealing with the Datastore to keep your model as small as you can, and this is why: consider a model with dozens of properties, each time you fetch an entity you'd need to fetch them all; network isn't an issue here, what is, is protobuf decoding and Python is not really good at it.

Comment: This is untrue. Expando properties can be indexed and queried on just like other properties; see [this section of the NDB docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#properties_by_string) for details.

Comment: Also, projections can be used to fetch only the required fields, so that the entire model need not be fetched and decoded.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for querying on Expando properties in NDB is a little different to how it's done in the old DB API, and is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#properties_by_string). Your query needs to look something like this:

```
user = users.all().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('is_active') == False, ndb.GenericProperty('activation_key) == act_key).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

is your custom User Model implemented with the `db` package or `ndb`?

for the first question if you only need to check if a user exists or not you could make a keys_only query `.all(keys_only=True).filter(...`

the error you are getting in when querying with the webapp2 User model is depending on the ndb package. with ndb the right syntax for the query is:

```
User.query().filter(User.is_active == False)
```

or

```
User.query(User.is_active == False)
```

of course you will need to query on the your custom User model.

Comment: See the following documentation about ndb queries: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop

Comment: @aschmid00 thanks for your quick response. I am using the webapp2_extras' user model which is implemented with ndb package. I have already tried this syntax and it raises: AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'is_active' for some reason. any idea ?

Comment: can you please update your question with your User model? subclassing UserModel or subclassing webapp2.models.User are 2 different things. your can't query one and get the other.